# Windows 10: rstudio reticulate keras tensorflow :: anaconda vs. miniconda vs. python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, rstudio, miniconda

The number of issues I'm having with a STABLE python environment operating beneath R/Rstudio is overwhelming... and the permutations of installation steps is far too flexible to inspire confidence with any approach.

First, I used `reticulate` to `uninstall_miniconda`. I wiped the computer of any trace of python. I have updated all packages, and reinstalled `reticulate`. I had `reticulate` `install_miniconda` (maybe I should have `reticulate` `install_python()` instead, but I don't understand why I wouldn't use conda when most R [Python context] documentation uses conda management... *so as a new user of python in R contexts, I want the documentation to be applicable to my work),* ...then I installed the latest `tensorflow` package and attempted to `install_tensorflow()`, but got `mapply()` errors (crazy that there is nothing on the internet about this error). I also got `mapply()` errors when attempting to run `install_keras()` from a new install of the `keras` package.

Further, nearly all of the reticulate documentation refers to using the "r-reticulate" conda environment... which again suggests that installation of miniconda or anaconda would be preferable.

After trying different ways to activate the conda environment, or install tensorflow first, or keras first, or activating the conda environment last... etc. etc... I had no other recourse than filing an issue on Github. So when attempting to report this issue, the prefill text says to use the following approach:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github(sprintf("rstudio/%s", c("reticulate", "tensorflow", "keras")))
if (is.null(reticulate::virtualenv_starter()))
  reticulate::install_python()
keras::install_keras()
```

Why is posit/rstudio suggesting using `install_python()` instead of `install_miniconda()`?
Why did `install_keras()` finally work after `install_python()` with no further interventions (like defining the `RETICULATE_PYTHON` environment variable, or running the function `use_python(my_python_directory)`), yet everything fails after running `install_miniconda()`?

I'm just looking for some explanation in hopes that it will facilitate my use of python with R, and in hopes that reticulate will operate predictably, or that I will be able to troubleshoot future issues without feeling like I'm on a scavenger hunt.

Here is my `sessionInfo()` in case it matters:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2    cli_3.6.1         tools_4.1.2       rstudioapi_0.15.0 rlang_1.1.1
```

Comment: It is very frustrating, especially with guidance like "the latest Python version is generally not advisable, ~2 minor versions behind .... is generally the sweet spot ...".

I particularly like the ~2, so not even definitive about that :-)

ref: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/510